# GCC standard compilation rules differing form distribution/version to another one: structures

Tags: xcode, gcc, struct, codeblocks

Some time ago i was using a Dev C++ IDE which runs under Windows and comes with MinGW (Windows port of GCC), now i moved to MAC OS X Leopard and I am using Code::Blocks IDE with GCC v4.2(apple modified version) which comes with XCode 3.2.2. I don't know if my problem depends upon distribution (Dev cpp) or compilator release, or maybe the fact that it's an Apple distribution of GCC, but i encountred this diffrence in declaring structured data.

In old Dev CPP, running on Windows i simply delcared this

const int max = 1000;

struct data{

```
   char thing[max];
   int anotherthing;
```

}

then i used referencing it to a function like this:

void some_function(data something)

---

It worked well. On Xcode version of the compiler using Code::Blocks IDE i get some errors and it won't compile.

```
    new types may not be defined in a return type
```

error: 'max' was not declared in this scope

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post the entire code snippet and the error that contains the line number? From the bit you posted you're missing a ; at the end of your struct definition but it's probably just a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 0):

I maked a comment with error content on the right line which it reefers to.

## include

using namespace std;
const int max = 1000;

typedef struct dato{

```
short pos;
char cont[max]; //error: 'max' was not declared in this scope
```

};

...Then comes the main function:

int main(){

```
char aArray[max]; //error: 'max' was not declared in this scope
int posz;
```

...continue whit good code

Comment: This isn't an answer.  If you do this, people may think the question is already answered.  It's better to edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you posted, I don't see anything wrong with it. It should compile without the error that you're getting. What happens if you move max into main's local scope? Does that error for aArray still come up?

The only other thing I could think of that might affect compilation are the switches passed to gcc. What does the command being passed by C::B look like when gcc is invoked?